# OnClick no Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, imagem, canvas

Tenho uma imagem e em cima dela está desenhado um Canvas. Preciso que quando clico na imagem ela abre no tamanho normal dela com o ojeto canvas desenhado. Por enquanto eu clico na imagem e só abre ela, o canvas não aparece. Isso porque eu não tenho o onClick e não sei como posso colocar.

Esse é o código que tenho para desenhar o canvas e abrir a imagem. Mas preciso de outra maneira para abrir a imagem com o canvas desenhado em cima dela.

```
    <div class="img_lau_a">
                                    <a href="http://cdn.smokeshot.com.br/imagens/<?= $l->fot_caminho ?>" target="_blank" class="pull-left" href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                        <p id="<?= $l->fot_nivel ?>" class="num_lau" style="position: absolute; left: 23px; color: <?= $color ?>; font-size: 60px; z-index: 1000"><b><?= $l->fot_nivel ?> </b></p>
                                        <div id="contentCanvas<?= $key ?>">
                                            <img id="foto<?= $key ?>" class="img_lau" style="max-width: 320px; border-left: 50px <?= $cor ?> solid; position: relative;" alt="img" src="http://cdn.smokeshot.com.br/imagens/<?= $l->fot_caminho ?>" onload='init(<?= $key ?>);'>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(i) {
        var img = document.getElementById("foto" + i);
        var cs = getComputedStyle(img);
        var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'));
        var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'));
        $('#contentCanvas' + i).html('<canvas id="myCanvas' + i + '" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" >');
        drawImg(img, cs, width, height, i);
    }
    function drawImg(img, cs, width, height, i) {
        var myCanvas = 'myCanvas' + i;
        var canvas = document.getElementById(myCanvas);
        var c = document.getElementById(myCanvas);
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        drawRetangle(context, width, height);
    }
    function drawRetangle(context, width, height) {
        position_x = parseInt(width) / 2;
        position_y = parseInt(height) / 2;

        position_x = parseInt(position_x) - 20;
        position_y = parseInt(position_y) - 17;

        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(position_x, position_y, 39, 34);
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = '#00FF00';
        context.stroke();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Eu coloquei um onClick chamando uma função javascript, e nessa função coloquei o código window.open('<?= base_url('NomeDoController/NomeDaFuncao')?>/'+$caminhoQueQuero, '_blank');

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar o onClick dinamicamente com o .setAttribute( "onClick", "Função( " + parametros + ")" ), caso os parametros da função sejam dinâmicos e .setAttribute( "onClick", "Função( parametros )" ) no caso de estático.

```
var a = document.getElementById( id );
    a.setAttribute( "onClick", "Função( parametros )" );
```

ou você pode tbm colocar como um addEventListener.

```
<script>
var b = document.getElementById( id );
    b.addEventListener( "click", addAgain );

//função com exemplo diferente que é chamada na função acima 
function addAgain()
{
    var c = document.getElementById( id );
        c.addEventListener( "click", function(){
        document.getElementById( id2 ).innerHTML = "Hello World";
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

muitas das pessoas querem usar o canvas para as coisas nao vazarem e consequentimente aumentar a janela, criar barra de rolagem ou fica deslizando no dedo.
caso seu problema seja esse(talvez você queira criar um jogo) você pode utilizar uma div com as seguintes propriedades do css:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:100vw;height:100vh;overflown:hidden;">
<img src="player.jpeg" onclick="sumir()">
</div>
```

o overflown faz com que qualquer coisa que esteja fora da div fique escondida!!!